# Greenplum install on GKE

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, greenplum

I am trying to install Greenplum on GKE using the directions [here](https://greenplum-kubernetes.docs.pivotal.io/1-12/installing.html)

I make it to step 12: but my operator pod is failing because it cannot pull the secret:

`kubectl logs -l app=greenplum-operator -n greenplum`

```
{"level":"INFO","ts":"2020-03-10T18:20:50.803Z","logger":"operator-setup","msg":"Go Info","Version":"go1.13.7","GOOS":"linux","GOARCH":"amd64"}
{"level":"INFO","ts":"2020-03-10T18:20:50.803Z","logger":"operator-setup","msg":"creating operator"}
W0310 18:20:50.803978       1 client_config.go:541] Neither --kubeconfig nor --master was specified.  Using the inClusterConfig.  This might not work.
W0310 18:20:50.804036       1 client_config.go:546] error creating inClusterConfig, falling back to default config: open /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token: permission denied
```

It looks like a permissions issue pulling the image, but the image pull test earlier in the instructions succeeded:

```
job.batch/greenplum-operator-fetch-test created
GREENPLUM-OPERATOR TEST OK
job.batch "greenplum-operator-fetch-test" deleted
```

Has anyone else run into this issue?

Comment: Have you checked all the prerequisites by following this link: [Greenplum-kubernetes.docs: Prepare GKE](https://greenplum-kubernetes.docs.pivotal.io/1-12/prepare-gke.html)?

Comment: Yes @DawidKruk I checked all the prerequisites. There is a problem with the documentation. Your comment is not helpful for solving this problem.

Comment: Yes, I see. My bad. I am glad that it works for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a bug the current documentation. You most likely did everything right. However, creating a GKE cluster with "Enable Kubernetes alpha features in this cluster" as listed on the prerequisites page (https://greenplum-kubernetes.docs.pivotal.io/1-12/prepare-gke.html) is no longer necessary. In fact, it's currently causing the exact issue you seem to be having. Try creating a GKE cluster following all of the documentation except make sure to NOT enable GKE "alpha features".

Comment: I just verified that the Pivotal documentation was incorrect, and a new cluster without the "Alpha features" allowed the images to be pulled. Thank you.